# Incrementing number in NSArray: Is there a shorter syntax?

Tags: objective-c

I have an array of several NSNumber. Once in a while I want to increment a number inside the array. Here's how I do that currently:

```
map[2] = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[map[2] integerValue] + 1]
```

I have to convert the number to NSInteger, then reconvert it to NSNumber after incrementing because NSArray only accept id.

This feels so wrong. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is the map really an array (i.e. is `2` the 3rd element, etc)?  Next are you just holding numbers in the map?  Could be all you need is a plain old C-array of `int`s.

Comment: @trojanfoe yes it's a normal NSMutableArray, and yes only numbers. Would it be simple to use C array in Obj-C functions?

Comment: Yes; it really depends if the size of the array varies, as that adds a lot of complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this a little by using the `@(...)` syntax:

```
map[@2] = @([map[@2]integerValue] + 1);
```

However, the general approach remains the same, because `NSNumber` objects are immutable. It would be easier if Cocoa provided `NSMutableNumber` class, but it is missing from the framework.

If you would like to avoid creating a new `NSNumber` instance each time the value is incremented, you could make a mutable object similar to `NSNumber` which would support in-place increments, decrements, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
NSMutableArray *foo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@1]];
foo[0] = @([foo[0] integerValue] + 1);
NSLog(@"---> %d", [foo[0] intValue]); // 2
```

In other words, you’re probably looking for the `@(expression)` syntax to box numbers into `NSNumber`s.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just because the map accept id*s*, it's also because NSNumbers are immutable, it's verbose but that's the only way to do it,sadly.

Comment: Depends on the requirements, which are unknown.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to change a number in the array repeatedly or frequently, I would implement that solution with some additional preparation, instead of using a non-mutable `NSNumber`.

eventually, you could achieve this kinda syntax after taking a little bit more effort to implement a new *class* and a *category* **(see below the steps!)**:

```
[_array numberAtIndex:0].numberValue++;
```

---

in my view such solution is more sophisticated in long term, and makes your code more readable later:

**GSNumber.h**

```
@interface GSNumber : NSObject

+ (instancetype)numberWithInteger:(NSInteger)value;
+ (instancetype)number;

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger numberValue;

- (NSInteger)integerValue;

@end
```

**GSNumber.m**

```
@implementation GSNumber

+ (instancetype)number {
    return [[GSNumber alloc] init];
}

+ (instancetype)numberWithInteger:(NSInteger)value {
    GSNumber *_number = [GSNumber number];
    _number.numberValue = value;
    return _number;
}

- (NSInteger)integerValue {
    return self.numberValue;
}

@end
```

---

I would also create a category on `NSArray`, it would look like this:

**NSArray+GSNumber.h**

```
#import "GSNumber.h"

@interface NSArray (GSNumber)

- (GSNumber *)numberAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

@end
```

**NSArray+GSNumber.m**

```
@implementation NSArray (GSNumber)

- (GSNumber *)numberAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    id _obj = [self objectAtIndex:index];
    return [_obj isKindOfClass:[GSNumber class]] ? _obj : nil;
}

@end
```

---

then you could do a much more readable code in initing:

```
NSArray *_array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[GSNumber numberWithInteger:12]]; // you don't need mutable array in this example
```

and you can increase the number value later without extra effort:

```
[_array numberAtIndex:0].numberValue++;

// OR

[_array numberAtIndex:0].numberValue += 1;
```

looks a bit more elegant and much more efficient in runtime.